# PHP | Order pictures array by rectangular

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I have an array like this one:

```
 array(
    0 => array(
       width => "213",
       height => "50"
    ),
    1 => array(
       width => "120",
       height => "204"
    )
 ) etc...
```

Now I want to order this array by the biggest rectangular in the length for example in this array it is the number with `width=>"213" and height=>"50"`

My try to do this was that, using `usort()`:

```
usort($images, function($a, $b) { 
    return $b['height'] - $a['width'];
});
```

But it sort's the pictures just for their size. Anybody a idea?

Comment: Please explain what's not working. Do you want to sort by width, or by height? Or some computed value like area?

Comment: why not just get the longest length of the two, then use that to sort it

Comment: "biggest rectangular" -- what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `length` as the `width` of the image -

```
usort($images, function($a, $b) { 
    return $b['width'] - $a['width'];
});
```

And if you mean by `area` of the rectangular image -

```
usort($images, function($a, $b) { 
    return ($b['height'] * $b['width']) - ($a['width'] * $a['height']);
});
```